# ReactiveSwift: Observe Managed Object changes with MutableProperty

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, reactive-cocoa, reactive-swift

My project has `CoreData` database with 1 root context and multiple sub contexts.
I have a `ViewModel` that contains an Item (`NSManagedObject`). When I changes something in an Item the persistence is made in the root context and then automatically merged into all sub-contexts.

I want to replace the `NSFetchedResultsController` with `ReactiveSwift` Signals / Properties, to observe changes in the item object.

ViewModel:

```
var itemProperty: MutableProperty<Item> = MutableProperty(contextItem)
```

ViewController:

```
self.viewModel.itemProperty.signal.observeValues{ (item: Item) in
     let newName = item.name
     print("name: \(newName!)" 
 }
```

After I change the item's name somewhere else, the changes are propagated to the `ViewModel` sub-context (the `NSFetchedResultsController` gets notified), BUT the signal never pushes a new `item` event.

Maybe because the `NSManagedObject` reference never changes? I know I can observe changes to specific properties in an object with `producer(forKeyPath: "propertyKeyPath" )`, but I don't want to observe just one specific property of the item, I want to observe ALL changes.

Is there a way to observe ANY change in all the object's properties ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently after a little research I found out ReactiveCocoa it's not so well prepared to work with Core Data. It is not possible to receive NSManagedObject updates with just ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveSwift.

One option could be updating the ItemProperty with each update from a NSFetchedResultsController and trigger a new event on the property's associated signal:

```
var entityProperty: MutableProperty<MyEntity>

override func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) 
{
    entityProperty.value = anObject as! MyEntity
}
```

Another option could be to get a signal for updates on specific properties in my entity:

```
var myEntity: MyEntity

// ReactiveObjectiveC
myEntity.rac_values(forKeyPath: "name", observer: self)

// ReactiveSwift
myEntity.reactive.signal(forKeyPath: "name")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could observe `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChange`.  This may be somewhat overkill, because it sends a notification when *any* change occurs to *any* objects(s).  But I've used it without any noticeable performance hit.  Here is the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnotification/name/1506884-nsmanagedobjectcontextobjectsdid).

The main drawback of `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChange` is that it does not give you the changed keys or values.  If you need that, realize that creating observers on all properties may not be as onerous as you think.  It can be done in a single loop, iterating over `NSEntityDescription.properties` or one of the other four similar properties listed at the bottom of [its documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsentitydescription/1425125-properties).

Comment: Yes! I am aware I can use the `NSManagedObejctContext` but I wanted to make the observation of changes completely with ReactiveSwift. 
Because If I use `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChange` I would be just using ReactiveSwift signals to replace the Delegate pattern.